# Is the [blank] worth the shake?

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains

I remember someone once telling me a saying in the form: "Is the [blank] worth the shake?"

The meaning was similar to the saying, "Is the end worth the means?"

I can't remember what the [blank] word was though. Has anyone heard of this saying before?

I think the term "shake" in this sense might mean amount of work, or hustle.

Comment: Thinking this though myself, the word `stick` makes sense to me here. `"Is the stick worth the shake?"` I'm not sure if anyone else would agree though :)

Comment: I've never heard of it, and neither, apparently, has Google.  As for *stick*, the only thing that comes up from googling "is the stick worth the shake" is this comment.

Comment: Too localised. There's not a single instance of *"worth the shake"* in Google Books, and checking on the Internet at large shows nothing relevant in the first several dozen occurrences.

Comment: Agree with FumbleFingers - the apparently correct answer didn't exist in cyberspace until 5 minutes ago.

Comment: It's possible that the phrase is localized. Maybe even adapted from a Spanish variation of the phrase (A Mexican friend told me the saying). I just remember having heard it and immediately thinking that the phrase made sense, but I can't remember the phrase itself. Weird how the mind works sometimes, right? Should I close this question?

Comment: Is it **is the tree worth the squeeze?**

Comment: @cornbreadninja: That didn't exist on the internet either until you wrote it.

Comment: ha!  I was mixing 'juice worth the squeeze' with 'fruit worth the shake' (of the tree, which put a certain Steve Miller song in my head).

Comment: It's almost certainly a reinterpretation of /wərθə'ʃek/ with the θ of _worth_ merging with the ð of _the_. In actual speech there wouldn't be any difference. In any event the idiom is _be worth a `quantifier`,_ and this special case, where the quantifier is of zero or negative value, is a Negative Polarity Item. Cf _*It's worth a damn_ w/ _It's not worth a damn._

Answer (score 1):

"Is the shit worth the shake" -  It's an Irish expression.

Comment: This is the only instance of it on the internet, though.

Comment: Sure we're only getting the internet over here now! Must be quite a colloquial phrase.

Comment: This isn't the phrase I was looking for, but it's an interesting phrase though. Can you explain the meaning or how it's used?

Comment: It's quite crude, but basically like you say, does the end justify the means.

Comment: "Jayz Lad, did you try shift her?" - "Nah man, I said to myself, is the shit worth the shake? And then I legged it away from her"- Sorry that's the kind of context we would use it in, in Dublin.